# Sorry for not being very specific - but what is this part of a URL?

Tags: web, url

**Just a quick question...**

What is this part in a URL called, and how do I set one up?

For example:  **sales**.jetbrains.com

Thanks!

Comment: it is subdomain, A short reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain

Answer (score 1):

It is a subdomain.

You see the DNS is a tree like structure. In DNS all domains are sub-domains (only a root domain is the exception but you can't use it anyway). A (google).com is a sub domain of the com domain and com domain is a top level domain

Answer (score 0):

This is called subdomains, if you own a website you can create as much as subdomain in it.

A short reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain